# How can I check if biometrics is available and enabled in react native?

Tags: react-native, biometrics

For my app I am using react-native NOT Expo.
I am trying to inform the user that they should turn on there FaceID if the phone is capable of doing it. If the phone has no FaceID because its an older phone the user cannot use the app. (This is just an example)

I found [react-native-biometrics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-biometrics) which has a method called `isSensorAvailable()`.

The problem that I have is that when I turn my FaceID off on my phone `isSensorAvailable()` returns: `available: false, biometryType: undefined`

When I turn FaceID ON: `available: true, biometryType: FaceID`

So how can I cover the scenario when the phone is capable of doing FaceID but I turned it off on the settings. Right now there is no way to know if it's just  the phone that is not capable of doing it or it is me who turned off FaceID in settings.

What would be the best way to solve this? Use a different library? Write everything in native code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find any solution for this?